# Pull an ID from mysql table and replace it with the corresponding name out of a different table

Tags: mysql, function, html-table

This is probably really confusing but try to follow...

So I have an array and foreach section as listed below

```
foreach($rows as $record){
$directorid = $record[director];


echo "

<tr class='row'><td width='74'><a href='workimgedit.php?id=$record[wid]'><div      class='workthumb'><img src='../img/work/$record[image]' class='wthumb'></div></td><td>$record[title] - $record[subtitle]</td><td>Director: $directorname, $record[crew1]</td>
<td>$record[player]</td><td>$record[code]</td>
<td class='link'><a href='workedit.php?id=$record[id]'>Edit</a></td>
</tr><tr class='offrow'><td colspan='6'></td></tr>
";
};
```

and I need to change the `$directorid` to actual name of that person and not the id, so I need to link to that table's `first_name` and `last_name` but I am in the middle of displaying another tables rows.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solutions is probably just to go ahead and store the other table with the first and last names in a "directorsArray". Then you can iterate through it each time you need to grab and name, and insert the correct data based on the matching Id.

1. Setup a "directorsArray" using a mySQL `SELECT` query
2. Place a for loop that iterates through that array within your existing code

I'll assume you can do step 1 by yourself, but here is step 2...

```
foreach($rows as $record){
    $directorid = $record[director];

    for($i=0;$i<count($directorsArray);$i++){
        if($directorsArray[$i]["directorId"]==$directorId){
            $directorName = $directorsArray[$i]["first_name"]." ".$directorsArray[$i]["last_name"];
        }
    }
    //...now you can echo "$directorName"
    echo "The director's name is: $directorName";

    echo "
    <tr class='row'><td width='74'><a href='workimgedit.php?id=$record[wid]'><div class='workthumb'><img src='../img/work/$record[image]' class='wthumb'></div></td><td>$record[title] - $record[subtitle]</td><td>Director: $directorname, $record[crew1]</td>
    <td>$record[player]</td><td>$record[code]</td>
    <td class='link'><a href='workedit.php?id=$record[id]'>Edit</a></td>
    </tr><tr class='offrow'><td colspan='6'></td></tr>
    ";
};
```

It may be better to try to use a mySQL `JOIN` statement however. Check out this question: [PHP MySQL Select ID from one table and information from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491770/php-mysql-select-id-from-one-table-and-information-from-another-table)